# Where can I get shapefiles for AE - U.S. Armed Forces – Europe AP - U.S. Armed Forces – Pacific PR - Puerto Rico?

Tags: shapefile, data, united-states

I need shapefiles for these:

```
AE - U.S. Armed Forces – Europe
AP - U.S. Armed Forces – Pacific
PR - Puerto Rico
```

Where can I find them ?

Answer (score 4):

AE and AP are postal service designations to get mail to US military personnel overseas, not real locations on a map. Puerto Rico is a US commonwealth, not a state, but not an independent country, either. If your mapping requirements include Puerto Rico, then you should include Guam, the Marshall Islands, and other US possessions as well.

If you spend too much time researching the location of US troops and military facilities, you may attract unwanted attention from those that protect them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to TIGER by the US Census Bureau. The link below contains a shapefile for all the counties in the USA.

ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/COUNTY/

The link below is a Military Facilities shapefile they maintain. It should at least have boundaries for the installations you are looking for.

ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/MIL/